# JavaFX - How to position alert dialog to the center of the screen?

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

It was positioning above the center of the screen. So I had the code below. It's not working as I need it. Can someone help with the solution?

```
   public static void show(String titleString, String messageString, AlertType status, String iconStr)
    {                
        Alert alert = new Alert(status);
        alert.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        alert.setTitle(titleString);
        alert.setHeaderText("");
        alert.setContentText(messageString);


        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int centerX = screenSize.width/2;
        int centerY = screenSize.height/2;

        alert.setX(centerX);
        alert.setY(centerY);
        alert.showAndWait();
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to take into consideration the alert size: `int centerX = screenSize.width/2- alert.getWidth()/2;`. Apply it to height as well.

Comment: It works! Thanks!